# How to get response in responseDecodable in Alamofire 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am getting two response from API. 
**In failure case**

```json
{"message":"Either your supplied Email ID or Password is incorrect","status":201,"data":{}}
```

**In success case**

```json
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "access_token": "7a1bfe8c85ef81c635d7d14b9e335984",
        "app_access_token": "168aa07e4966186447694e95e4127fb5",
       }
}
```

I am parsing the data into a single structure using **decodeIfPresent** with optional. Is there any better way to parse the data without optional using failure structure and success structure?
**Any guidance always be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

you can use swiftJSON pod and parse data in JSON this is what i do for my api responce and handle it in json you can use and edit in your way

```
func ProfileApi(url : String , parameters : [String : String]){
    
    Alamofire.request(url , method : .post , parameters : parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess
        {
            print("API data recived")
            let DiseaseCatagory : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            // print(plotCatagory[0]["name"])
            
            //self.SelectedLevelIDArray = []
            if let data = DiseaseCatagory.dictionaryObject
            {
                if let error = data["error_code"] as? Int{
                    print(error)
                    if error == 0{
                        
                        if let data1 = data["data"] as? [String : Any]
                        {
                            print(data1)
                            if let PostDataRecieved = data1["about"] as? [[String : Any]]
                            {
                                print(PostDataRecieved)
                                var i = 0
                                
                                while(i < PostDataRecieved.count){
                                    
                                    self.ProfileName = PostDataRecieved[i]["first_name"] as! String
                                    self.ProfileGender = PostDataRecieved[i]["gender"] as! String
                                    self.ProfileEmail = PostDataRecieved[i]["email"] as! String
                                    self.ProfileCountry = PostDataRecieved[i]["country"] as! String
                                    self.ProfileDOB = PostDataRecieved[i]["dob"] as! String
                                    self.profileImageUrl = PostDataRecieved[i]["profile_picture"] as! String
                                    if let lastName = PostDataRecieved[i]["last_name"] as? String{
                                        
                                        self.profileLastName = lastName
                                        self.LastNameTextField.text = lastName
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    i = i + 1
                                }
                            }
                            self.AssignValues()
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                
                                self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 0.5)
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }else{
                        if let error = data["error_string"] as? String{
                            let signUpAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Signup Error!", message: error, preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                            signUpAlert.addAction(okButton)
                            self.present(signUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 0.5)
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            
            print("Error : \(response.result.error)")
            let signUpAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Connection Error!", message: "Please check internet connection and try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            signUpAlert.addAction(okButton)
            self.present(signUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

this the JSON responce which i am handling

```
{"error_code":0,"error_string":"","data":{"about":[{"id":"2","user_name":"","first_name":"Mazeda","last_name":"Khanam","mobile_no":"07387276289","email":"mazedakhanam@yahoo.co.uk","profile_picture":"user_icon.jpeg","gender":"female","profession":"Mum","dob":"1984-09-06","mood_status":"Hey There!","registered_time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","account_verified":"1","login_flag":"1","country":"United Kingdom","added_time":"2017-02-23 15:42:54","status":"1","android_push_token":"","ios_push_token":""}],"photo":[]}}
```

Comment: Don't want to use third party library just as swiftJSON. want to handle in Codable protocol.

Comment: its the most elegent library i came across to handle JSON there are no side effects

Comment: Appreciated, but Codable is native functionality provided by Swift. Why would I use a third-party library instead of native functionality?